# Java web app error 404 page - path, not load css

Tags: java, web.xml

I have error page in my `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/page404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

When i go to "not existing page" like this: `www.localhost:8080/notexistingpage` it's normaly show my error page (css file is ok).

But if I go to `www.localhost:8080/notexistingpage/notexistingfolder` my **error page not load css** file and other image on page.

How? Why? Where is a problem?

I try to find some solution on google, I didn't find anything about this problem.

Comment: Try to post the ful stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post the import of your page 404 to check how you did with resources. Probably you didn't use the Context. What is the server do you use?